# Want To Collect The Same string of header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates, multiple-columns

I have header of sheet as

```
'''
+--------------+------------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+
| usa_alaska   | usa_california   | france_paris   | italy_roma   | france_lyon   |
|--------------+------------------+----------------+--------------+---------------|
+--------------+------------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+
'''
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns = 'usa_alaska  usa_california  france_paris  italy_roma  france_lyon'.split())
```

I want to separate the headers by country and region in a way so that when I call `france`, I should get `paris` and `lyon` as columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a MultiIndex from your column names:

Suppose this dataframe:

```
>>> df
   usa_alaska  usa_california  france_paris  italy_roma  france_lyon
0           1               2             3           4            5
```

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Output

```
>>> df
  france       italy    usa           
    lyon paris  roma alaska california
0      5     3     4      1          2

>>> df['france']
   paris  lyon
0      3     5
```